# Has_many through association with sub-groupings (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4

**BACKGROUND:** Users have many Communities via a has_many :through association.

**OBJECTIVE:** I'd like to allow users to save certain favorite 'community groups'. For instance, if User A has Community A, Community B, and Community C - they might want to specify  the community group of (Community A **and** Community C) as one they particularly like. The sub-grouping could be comprised any number of communities (2 or more).

How would I best approach this on the database side?

Comment: In math terms is a group a set of A + C or A & C (common elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I think I would do is to create two models: Community and CommunityGroup, and then associate them with `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` dependent if you want to save any information on Community-Group relationship (probably not). It would be easy to quickly fetch all communities in a group, etc.